# How to redirect to protected route after successful login?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am working on an authentication system using react at front. I am storing token which comes from  my backend server to localStorage and i want user to redirect to dashboard page when there is a token present in localStorage. Every time i login using correct credentials i get token but not redirecting to dashboard page. But when i change route in url it works. I am using react context api.

> AuthContext.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext();
export default AuthContext;
```

> AuthState.js

```
import React, { useReducer, useState } from "react";
import AuthContext from "./AuthContext";
import { SUCCESS_LOGIN } from "../types";
import AuthReducers from "./AuthReducers";
import Axios from "axios";
const AuthState = ({ children }) => {
  //setting up initial state for authcontext
  const initialState = {
    userAuth: null,
    userLoading: false,
    token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
    errors: null,
  };
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducers, initialState);

  //logging user in
  const loginUser = async (userData) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    try {
      //posting to api
      const res = await Axios.post("/api/user/login", userData, config);
      console.log(res.data);
      dispatch({
        type: SUCCESS_LOGIN,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
    }
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        userAuth: state.userAuth,
        errors: state.errors,
        token: state.token,
        loginUser,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthState;
```

> AuthReducers.js

```
import { SUCCESS_LOGIN } from "../types";

export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SUCCESS_LOGIN:
      const token = action.payload.token;
      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
      return {
        ...state,
        userAuth: true,
        userLoading: true,
        errors: null,
        token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

> Login.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText } from "reactstrap";
import styles from "./login.module.css";
import AuthContext from "../../context/AuthContext/AuthContext";

const Login = (props) => {
  //grabbing states from authContext
  const { loginUser, userAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);

  let history = useHistory();
  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  //pulling email and password from state
  const { email, password } = credentials;

  //method to handle changes on input fields
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setCredentials({
      ...credentials,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  //method to handle login when user submits the form
  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    loginUser({ email, password });
    console.log(userAuth);
    if (userAuth) {
      history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  };
  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label for="email">Email</Label>
        <Input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          placeholder="Enter your email"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label for="password">Password</Label>
        <Input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          value={password}
          placeholder="Enter password"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </FormGroup>

      <Button className={styles.loginBtn}>Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

> PrivateRoute.js

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthContext from "../../context/AuthContext/AuthContext";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { token, userAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) =>
          token ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in `Login.js`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (userAuth) {
      history.push("/dashboard");
    }
},[userAuth,history])
```

Its happening because when you do handleLogin click functionality you dont have userAuth at that time as true(its taking previous value). Because context update change is not available in `handleLogin` function . Instead track `userAuth`  in `useEffect`

Comment: Great just remove push logic from `handleLogin` function as it will handle in `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to redirect the user after successful login via your `handleLogin()` function, it won't work because of this:

```
if (userAuth) {
      history.push("/dashboard");
}
```

The above will not run, because `userAuth` won't change until the component re-renders, after which, the function will have finished executing. You should either return something from your `loginUser()` action, and redirect based on its return of a successful "login", or implement conditional rendering inside of the Login component, like so:

```
return userAuth
    ? <Redirect to="/dashboard" />    // redirect if userAuth == true
    : (
        // your Login JSX    // if userAuth == false, render Login form
    )
```